# How do I initial a torch NCHW channel last tensor with NHWC data?

Tags: pytorch, torch

Now I have a tensor whose memory format and shape both are NHWC. If I want to change it to NCHW shape and channel last, like the result of this:

```
x = x.to(memory_format=torch.channels_last)
```

Which have NCHW shape but channel stride is 1. So It should cause no memory movement. Is there a way to realize it without memory overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Using `x = torch.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)` should not cause any significant overhead. Since C = 1, the contiguity of the data is maintained, thus the data buffer is left untouched.

```py
import torch

t = torch.rand(5, 224, 224, 1)
print(f"is t contiguous? {t.is_contiguous()}")  # returns True
t = t.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
print(f"is t contiguous? {t.is_contiguous()}")  # returns True, again
```